# Using {*} in Tcl

Tags: variables, tcl, variable-declaration

I am reading the book **Tcl/Tk, Third Edition: A Developer's Guide** and found the following piece of code in page number 42.

```
# This works
set nameANDvalue "a 2"
set { ∗ }$nameANDvalue
puts $a
```

I tried to run the same in tcl shell and got the following error

```
% set nameANDvalue "a 2"
    set { * }$nameANDvalue
    puts $a
a 2
% extra characters after close-brace
% can't read "a": no such variable
%
```

What is my mistake here ?

Comment: Is it really saying that _with the spaces?_ That would be a problem with the book.

Comment: No Donal, I typed with a space by mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there shouldn't be spaces within the braces:

```
set {*}$nameANDvalue
```

FYI - when you have the spaces, it is taking `*` (with space before and after) as the variable name... so you could, for example, `set { * } fubar`